# No plural forms for "You've earned this badge N times"

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, localization, plurals

The text of tooltip message showed for the green tick next to badge icon requires plural forms [in Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40263966?q=key%3Aa51daf187617ff4a487793d022ee2b01):

> [image: badge time]

Comment: But the screenshot does show it in plural form. Had you meant to show a *working* example rather than a *broken* example?

Comment: @JasonBassford I suggest that you don't have Transifex account, and you don't know how the translations work on SE sites. I will explain you briefly. For languages other than English there should be three plural forms for string: one (1, 21, 31 ...), two (2-4, 22-24, 32-34 ...), many (any other). Mentioned string has only one (unspecified) form, hence it can't be translated correctly e.g. to Russian. If you are intersting in some details you can read [the post on ruso.meta](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1032/176217) about translations.

Comment: My point is that the screenshots you use should complement the question you're asking, so it's clear to everybody viewing the images what you're trying to explain.

Comment: @JasonBassford it cannot be clear to everybody here since English language sites are not affected. I can post an image from ruSO, but you need to know Russian to understand it. Moreover for developers who have access to Transifex the provided link is enough to comprehend the issue. Current image just for clarifying the place where tooltip is shown.

Comment: @JasonBassford if you want even more complicated, look at [Mozilla Localization guidelines.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Localization/Localization_and_Plurals)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build (rev > 2018.7.2.30925).

Comment: Since the current build is 30924 I think you meant `>=` instead of `>`. Am I right?

Comment: no, each commit now gets a separate number, and those are propagated from our dev tier - usually multiple commits go out per prod build together. Another commit was already in the pipe when I pushed the fix...